# Entity Framework: Self-join error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following class:

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /* Other properties */

    public int LegacyId { get; set; }
    public int LegacyParentId { get; set; }

    public int? ApplicationSupersessionId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Application> ApplicationSupersessions { get; set; }

    public Application()
    {
        ApplicationSupersessions = new List<Application>();
    }
}
```

Where `ApplicationSupersessions` is an optional self-joined entity. I have data already added to my `Applications` table and I'm trying to adjust the data, which currently looks like this:

[image]

But I need Applications `5413` and `5414` to have an `ApplicationSupersessionId` of `5415` as that is what it looks like in our Legacy system, hence why I have added the 2 `Legacy` columns

So I've tried the following:

```
var applications = CatalogueContext.Applications.ToList();

foreach (var application in applications)
{
    var legacyChildren = applications.Where(x => 
        x.LegacyParentId == application.LegacyId).ToList();

    if(legacyChildren.Any())
    {
        foreach(var child in legacyChildren)
        {
            application.ApplicationSupersessions.Add(child);
        }

       CatalogueContext.Entry(application).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}

CatalogueContext.SaveChanges();
```

But I get the following error on the line `CatalogueContext.Entry(application).State = EntityState.Modified;`:

[image]

Comment: "Applications 5413 and 5414 will have an ApplicationSupersessionId of 5415."

In the screeshot its NULL?

Comment: Thats because of the error I'm getting, before I tell the context the entity has been modified I see those 2 applications in `5415` list of `ApplicationSupersessions`

Comment: Nope, CF with Migrations enabled

Comment: please put a srceenshot with the breakpoint at 'var application'...want to see what this application has before u get that error.

Comment: What specifically will you need? As my `Application` object is quite big

Comment: CatalogueContext.Applications.ToList() want to see this list...one more thing for the CodeFirst plz check the primary keys once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55000/discussion-between-newton-sheikh-and-biffbaffboff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. I had the relationship set up wrong in my Configuration.

I had this:

```
HasOptional(x => x.ApplicationSupersessions)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ApplicationSupersessionId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

When it should have been this:

```
HasMany(x => x.ApplicationSupersessions)
    .WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ApplicationSupersessionId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I'm not sure what the difference is and whether or not its an EF bug?

Comment: @NewtonSheikh any idea what the difference is? I'm unable to find anything which is why I was confused :S